# How can I set the “main file” in Activator?

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator, scala.js

I have a play framework project with ScalaJS front-end. I took the SBT setup from https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example.

When I use Typesafe's Activator in UI mode, all works fine *except* of running the application. For some reason, it uses the main class from the ScalaJS sub-project (`app.XYZApp`) instead of taking them from the play framework sub-project.

How can I force the activator to use the play framework's main class (whatever it is)?

Interestingly, this happens only under OS X and Linux but not under Windows.

Comment: If you have an example app (ideally with link to GitHub), it would be easier for us to have a look at this and help you.